# Loop through a table and assign foreign key to new record if null

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I am working on an SQL Database

I have a Table Users

```
 Id   Name   Age    AddressId
----+------+------+-----------
```

Where AddressId is a foreign key to a table names Addresses

The Addresses Table:

```
 Id   Country   State  City   ZipCode
----+---------+------+------+---------
```

I need an SQL Script, that loops through all the users and If the AddressId of that user is null, Create a new record in the Addresses Table with default Values and assign it to the user as a foreign key

Something like this in SQL script:

```
Foreach (User in Users)
    If(user.AddressId==null)
        INSERT INTO Addresses values('DefaultCountry', 'DefaultState', 'DefaultCity', 99999)
        User.AddressId= the id of the newly created row
```

**EDIT**
It is a one-to-one relationship

thanks for any help

Comment: If you are assigning default addresses then you need to insrt only one row in the addresses table and refer that addressId in the users table right?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that this is a one-to-one relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` and `output` to do this without a loop.

```
declare @IDs table(UserId int, AddressId int);

merge Addresses as T
using (select Id, 'DefaultCountry', 'DefaultState', 'DefaultCity', 99999
       from Users
       where AddressID is null) as S (UserId, Country, State, City, ZipCode)
on 0 = 1
when not matched then
  insert(Country, State, City, ZipCode) 
    values (S.Country, S.State, S.City, S.ZipCode)
output S.UserId, inserted.Id into @IDs;

update Users
set AddressId = IDs.AddressID
from @IDs as IDs
where Users.Id = IDs.UserId;
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/71095)

If you only need to add one address and connect that one to all users that have none use this instead.

```
declare @AddressId int;

insert into Addresses(Country, State, City, ZipCode)
  values('DefaultCountry', 'DefaultState', 'DefaultCity', 99999);

set @AddressId = scope_identity();

update Users
set AddressId = @AddressId
where AddressId is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #Users
(
    id int,
    AddressID int
)

insert into #Users(id, AddressID)values(1, 1)
insert into #Users(id, AddressID)values(2, null)

create table #Address
(
    id int Identity(1,1),
    nam varchar(100)
)

declare @id int
declare @AddressID int
declare @NewAddressID int

declare cur cursor for Select id, AddressID from #Users Where AddressID is null
open cur
Fetch next from cur into @id, @AddressID
While(@@Fetch_Status = 0)
Begin
    Fetch next from cur into @id, @AddressID
    insert into #Address(nam)values(NEWID())
    Set @NewAddressID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    Update #Users
    Set AddressID = @NewAddressID
    Where id = @id
End

Deallocate cur

SELECT * FROM #Address
SELECT * FROM #Users
drop table #Address
drop table #Users
```