# How do I add new records where a foreign key is null?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have table A:

| ID | B_ID (foreign key to B) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | (null) |
| 3 | (null) |

and table B:

| ID | FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | (null) |

Because of some new app structure, we need all entries in table A to have a corresponding entry in table B. Is there a SQL command (we're using Oracle) that can create these rows in table B and then update table A's foreign key?

In other words, the result should look like this:

A:

| ID | B_ID (foreign key to B) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

B:

| ID | FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | (null) |
| 3 | (null) |
| 4 | (null) |

(similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750447/loop-through-a-table-and-assign-foreign-key-to-new-record-if-null), but that is using SQL Server and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74010687/create-new-records-in-one-table-a-and-add-as-foreign-key-to-table-b-if-the-forei) using Postgres)

Comment: How do you identify which FK values will be assigned to which of original rows (2 or 3)?

Comment: @astentx it doesn't matter; all of the new rows should just have `null` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Littlefoot's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76871178/9555513) is great and helped me a lot, but the solution I used is different enough that I think it's worth its own answer.

First, create a sequence that will track the new id's in B:

```sql
declare
n number;
begin
SELECT MAX(ID) into n FROM "TABLE_B";
execute immediate 'create sequence seq increment by 1 start with ' || n;
end;
/
```

Then create the B rows filled with null values:

```
INSERT
INTO "B" (
  FIELD
)
SELECT 
  null
FROM "A" where "B_ID" is null;
```

Then update A with the new ID's:

```
update "A" set "B_ID" = seq.nextval where "B_ID" is null;
```

and drop the temporary sequence:

```
drop sequence seq;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do that with a deferrable foreign key constraint. Here's an example.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table tb
  2    (id    number primary key,
  3     field number
  4    );

Table created.
```

Note the way foreign key is created; it lets you create rows WITHOUT parent keys. Check is being done on commit:

```
SQL> create table ta
  2    (id    number primary key,
  3     b_id  number,
  4     --
  5     constraint fk_ab foreign key (b_id) references tb (id)
  6       initially deferred deferrable
  7    );

Table created.
```

Sample rows:

```
SQL> insert into tb (id, field) values (2, null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into ta (id, b_id)
  2    select 1, 2    from dual union all
  3    select 2, null from dual union all
  4    select 3, null from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Now, create a sequence which will be used to populate missing foreign key values:

```
SQL> select max(id) from tb;

   MAX(ID)
----------
         2
```

Sequence starts with the next available value (3 in this case):

```
SQL> create sequence seq start with 3;

Sequence created.
```

OK; update `ta` table with the sequence values:

```
SQL> update ta set b_id = seq.nextval
  2    where b_id is null;

2 rows updated.

SQL> select * From ta;

        ID       B_ID
---------- ----------
         1          2
         2          3      --> this ...
         3          4      --> ... and this B_ID were created
```

Finally, populate master table with missing values. There are numerous ways to do that - I chose to use the MINUS set operator:

```
SQL> insert into tb (id)
  2    select b_id
  3    from ta
  4    minus
  5    select id
  6    from tb;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from tb;

        ID      FIELD
---------- ----------
         2
         3                   --> this ...
         4                   --> ... and this row have been added

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

That's it.